# Display the sub-subcategories of the current subcategories in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hierarchical, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to Show sub-subcategories under current subcategory in Woocommerce like [this Website](http://www.qs-adhesivos.es/app/productos/productos.asp?idioma=en).

I've 2 parents categories "Products" and "Sectors". Then I've a menu link that go to both.

When I'm in "Products" I want to see the picture of the subcategory, the title of category and then all the sub-subcategories with the title and link to them.

For Example, the parent category is "Products", Construction is the subcategory, and Sealants & adhesives, waterproofing, plyurethane foams… are sub-subcategories.

Sealants & Mastics is the subcategory, and ACETIC SILICONE SEALANT, NEUTRAL SILICONE SEALANT, ACRYLIC SEALANT… are sub-subcategories…

Here is a screenshot that explains it better:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code to be used in here is very similar to your previous question thread. But we use a **specific action hook** with some few changes to get the sub-subcategories of the subcategories:

```
// Displaying the sub-subcategories of the current subategories
add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory', 'display_subsubcategories_list', 20, 1 );
function display_subsubcategories_list( $category ) {
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

    // Get sub-subcategories of the current subcategory
    $terms    = get_terms([
        'taxonomy'    => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty'  => true,
        'parent'      => $category->term_id
    ]);

    if( count($terms) > 0 ) :

    echo '<ul class="subcategories-list" style="list-style: none; border: solid 1px #ddd; border-bottom: none;">';

    // Loop through product sub-subcategories WP_Term Objects
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );

        echo '<li class="'. $term->slug .'" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;"><a href="'. $term_link .'">'. $term->name .'</a></li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';

    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Notes:** The `woocommerce_after_subcategory` action hook is located on `content-product_cat.php` template file, which handle subcategories to be displayed as products are *(with an image and a linked term name).* 
>   For that your main categories needs to have the option "Display type" set on "Subcategory".

Comment: One more question, Where I can change the font color and background color of the "subcategory title" (font color white and backgroung black like the screenshot)?

Comment: @Alvaro either in the themes style.css file or if you're using a theme where you have an interface with options for the look, you'll change it there. If you're new to styling read through some basic CSS tutorials online.